# Checkout Page Endless Loading Icon

Tags: magento2, paypal, bug, credit-card

On the checkout page, after entering in credit card information and clicking *Place Order* the page will show the loading icon and it will never stop. There are no errors in the magento logs or in the server logs. I turned on Paypal debug and the log shows Approved, but the transaction is not going through in paypal or magento.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I called PayPal again after they said it was a Magento error. The new PayPal rep explained to me that I was using a Legacy version of PayPal Payments Pro that is not supported by Magento 2. I had to create a new PayPal account that included PayPal Manager, and then it began working.

Answer (score 0):

Open your chrome developer tool by hitting F12 and go to the network tab(Be sure to open it before proceeding the payment info step). After entering the credit card details and clicking the proceed button you will see a request in this tab. Click this request to see the details to debug.

[image]

Comment: I added my screenshot to the post. How can I use this to solve my issue?

Comment: There is no visible crash. you have to debug the checkout code specifically  the payment code in js. Might be there is some code that should be executed after getting the response but its not executing.

Comment: How would I go about forcing it to execute? Sorry, I don't know enough to debug the js

Comment: Sorry Josiah I haven't touched specifically this part of magento 2 yet. But I can give you the path of the js file where you can start debugging ("Magento root"/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/default.js). Also you might have to check in 3rd party modules that have someone override this js, If yes then you have to debug that file too.

Answer (score 0):

Josiah, please look into the response tab of that xhr request. Although it gives 200 OK response that request's answer could still contain an error, making js fail to decode the answer and continue. There doesn't seem to be any js error, so my guess it that your answer should be in that response.